# Как правильно произносить аббревиатуру СМР (строительно-монтажные работы)?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно произносить аббревиатуру СМР (строительно-монтажные работы)?

Comment: Эс-эм-эр? А какие еще варианты есть?

Comment: СэМэЭр, ЭсМэЭр или ЭсЭмЭр???

Comment: Лично я придерживаюсь 2-ого варианта произношения, мои коллеги - 1-ого... Хочу все же определиться с произношением.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я слышала только СэМэЭр - по аналогии с США. Разговорный вариант закрепился в общей речи. А правил произношения этой аббревиатуры пока, видимо, нет.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_91

Буквенно-звуковые аббревиатуры состоят как из названий начальных букв, так и из начальных звуков слов, входящих в исходное словосочетание: ЦСКА [цэ-эс-ка].

За аббревиатурой США по традиции закрепилось произношение [сэ-шэ-а], т. е. она является особой аббревиатурой: читается по буквам, но не так, как это принято в литературном языке, а так, как буквы С [эс] и Ш [ша] называют в разговорной речи.Вот и с СМР то же произошло - чтение букв, как в разговорной речи, по правилам экономии средств, такая сейчас в языке тенденция.

Comment: тогда уж СэМэРэ! Вот и еще вариант! :)

Answer (score 0):

Странно, но почему-то все поголовно ЗАБЫЛИ, что существуют как аббревиатуры, так и акронимы.
Вот определение акронима из Википедии:
Акро́ним (от греч. άκρος — высший, крайний + όνυμος — имя) — вид аббревиатуры, образованной начальными звуками (напр. НАТО, вуз, НАСА, ТАСС).

Позволю себе повторить, что аббревиатуры произносятся по названию букв в алфавите (напр. "эр-эс-эф-эс-эр" - "РСФСР"), а акронимы - читаются, как слово (напр. "УЕФА"). Во времена СССР дикторы телевидения говорили по нормам русского языка и я не помню "ляпов" типа "сэ-шэ-а", потому, что "США" всегда было акронимом и произносилось как слово "сша", например, как и "МХАТ". Но потом, просторечные, по сути малограмотные, формы вытеснили произносительные нормы и теперь имеем, что имеем, причем, уже закрепленное в "правилах".

Comment: Какое отношение это имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @случайныйпрохожий: Это комментарий, не содержащий ответа на заданный вопрос.